# How to Generate Web.xml flle on maven project

Tags: java, maven, web.xml

I am trying to deploy a maven project locally. Surprisingly, i don't have a web.xml file and am unsure how to generate one. I've found directions on how to generate a missing web.xml for a dynamic web project, but that is not possible to use those steps for my maven build. Also, I am reading that it's possible for maven to generate the web.xml for you when the project is CREATED. However, I already created it and the web.xml is missing and I need to make a new one.

Thanks,
Angel

Comment: Depending on your app configuration, if a web.xml file is not needed, you can simply set the `<failOnMissingWebXml>` to false in the `<configuration>` of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web.xml` is usually provided in source, it is not something that maven or any build tool has to generate, So just create a text file rename it as `web.xml` and fill it in

Comment: Where to place `web.xml` file and how to call it in maven

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is three years now, but just in case anybody is still wondering how to do it : In eclipse , right click on your project's name then select Java EE Tools-> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub. And voila, the web.xml file is automatically created.